# GiantBomb API request getting HTML instead of JSON, Nodejs Request Module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web, request

Hey I'm trying to make a query to the giant bomb API, for some reason I am getting back a bunch of HTML/js instead of a JSON object. When I enter the query in the browser I get the JSON as expected.

```
var giantBombAPI = 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api';
 var searchString = giantBombAPI + '/search?api_key=' + apiKey +
    '&format=json' + '&query=' + searchTerms + "&resources=game";

//Make our request to the API
request.get({uri: searchString},function (err, res, body) {

    jsonRes = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Also it worked yesterday :P. 
I am plugging in "warcraft" for searchterms to test.

I am using the Nodejs request module.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an error. What's the HTML look like? Can you place it in a gist?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cruzj6/c9c3b8c3faf1fa4e1be5

Comment: hmmm reading that now, i'm not doing anything "sketchy" :P

Comment: This is the actual full request string (minus api key): http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search?api_key=9999&format=json&query=warcraft&resources=game

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, the API now requires a custom user agent:

```
request.get({uri: searchString, headers:{'user-agent' : '<CUSTOM>'}}, 
function (err, res, body) {
     //....
}
```